# Script is truncating entire file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script in Powershell that I'm having some trouble with.

```
$Path = 'C:\Projects\Powershell\TEst'
$MiddleName = 'torres'

CD $Path


Get-ChildItem .\ -filter *PCPLink*| ForEach-Object {
$content = Get-Content $_.FullName  | 
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $MiddleName, $MiddleName[0]} |out-file $_.FullName -force
}
```

It's pretty straight forward, the issue I'm having is

I need this to look for multiple files that share the filename filter, for each file i need it to spit out a file with the same name and just the first character value `$MiddleName` truncated. **NOT THE ENTIRE FILE**

But when I change the script to output $_.Fullname, the files are empty. What am I missing?

So the file would look like

```
Torres
Tom
Tony
Tickle
```

I'm expecting

```
T
Tom
Tony
Tickle
```

Actual output from this script is Blank

It ***DOES*** pick up the two files I have it filtered to match.

Comment: Why are you trying to capture something in `$Content` if you are piping to `Out-File`?

Comment: The original script I had had get content in parens, I needed to avoid that because it wasn't working how I intended, do you have a solution for this ? @TheMadTechnician

Comment: I think I've got it. I'll get you an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are piping `Get-Content` to a `ForEach` loop, and then to `Out-File`, and that's all fine and dandy, but by the time you get to `Out-File` your `$_` object is no longer representative of the file being affected, it is now the content of the file from the `Get-Content` cmdlet.

```
$Path = 'C:\Projects\Powershell\TEst'
$MiddleName = 'torres'
ForEach($File in (Get-ChildItem $Path -filter '*.csv')){
(Get-Content $File.FullName) -replace $MiddleName, $MiddleName[0] |out-file $File.FullName -force
}
```

Comment: Ahhh shoot, I think my original script would've worked if I removed the pipe after (Get-Content $File.FullName) ...Thanks!